# How to make SVG responsive in D3 with viewbox?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, responsive

I have noticed that in various examples, an SVG is responsive (changes size in response to changes in window size) and sometimes it is not responsive when using viewbox / preserveAspectRatio.
Here is a very simple example. I am using viewbox and preseverAspectiRatio on the SVG element like every other example, but yet, it is not responsive, why?

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<div id ="chart"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>

<script>
var svgContainer = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 200)
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 100 100")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")

 //Draw the Circle
var circle = svgContainer.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 50)
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("r", 50);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by responsive? Should it re-scale on screen resize?

Comment: yes, sorry, please see revised question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your svg is not resize because you have specified a fixed with for the svg container of `200x200`.

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 200) // setting fixed width
  .attr("height", 200) // setting fixed width
```

One solution is to change these to percentages, which will rescale to the size of its parent.

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", '100%') // percent width
  .attr("height", 100%) // percent height
```

Another possible solution is to use the [`Window#resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) event, and change the size of the svg based on the changes.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
// select svg and resize accordingly
});
```

I should add that in chrome you can use [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) to watch for changes to the svg parents size, and resize the svg accordingly from that.

```
    const resizeOb = new ResizeObserver((entries: any[]) => {
      for (const entry of entries) {
        const cr = entry.contentRect;
        const width = cr.width; // parent width
        const height = cr.height; // parent height
        // resize svg
      }
    });
    this.resizeOb.observe(svgParentElement);
```